# Read specific rows of excel file in angular using xlsx package

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, angular-directive

I have read excel file in angular11 using xlsx package.

the bellow code read all rows which start from first row if data available and also skip from empty row.
Now I want to start reading from specific row and also want to read empty row?

```
const target:DataTransfer=<DataTransfer>(evt.target); 
    if(target.files.length!==1) throw new Error('Can not select multiple
    files');   const reader:FileReader=new FileReader();  
    reader.onload=(e:any)=>{
        const bstr:string=e.target.result;
        const wb:XLSX.WorkBook=XLSX.read(bstr,{type:'binary'});
        const wsname:string=wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws:XLSX.WorkSheet=wb.Sheets[wsname];
        // console.log(ws);
        this.ExcelData=(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws ,{header:1}));
        console.log(this.ExcelData);
    
      };   reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
```